# not getting the exact name to the spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

hi I created two spinners and I given two different default values to the two spinners,but its taking only one value as the default, if I set only fromtext or totext its getting correctly, when I setting both its not taking. I'm not understanding where the fault occurs.

```
 public class UniqueConverter extends Fragment {

    private Spinner fromDetails, toDetails;
    private EditText fromInput, toInput;

    public static UniqueConverter setArguments(int position) {
        UniqueConverter uniqueConverter = new UniqueConverter();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("position", position);
        uniqueConverter.setArguments(args);
        return uniqueConverter;
    }

 @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uniquelayout, container, false);

        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        onInitVies(view);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.temperatureform), "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
                break;
            case 1:
                setAdapter(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightform), "Kilograms", "Grams");
                break;
 return view;
    }

    private void setAdapter(String[] spinnerItems, String fromDefaultText, String toDefaultText) {
        fromDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText));
        toDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.spinner_item,spinnerItems,toDefaultText));
    }

    private void onInitVies(View view) {
        fromDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        toDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

        fromInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
        toInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toInput);
    }
}
```

my string-array:

```
<string-array name="temperatureform">
        <item name="c">Celsius</item>
        <item name="f">Fahrenheit</item>
        <item name="k">Kelvin</item>
    </string-array>
```

spinnerAdapter:

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        Context context;
        String[] objects;
        String firstElement;
        boolean isFirstTime;

        public CustomSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects, String defaultText) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.context = context;
            this.objects = objects;
            this.isFirstTime = true;
            setDefaultText(defaultText);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (isFirstTime) {
                objects[0] = firstElement;
                isFirstTime = false;
            }
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public void setDefaultText(String defaultText) {
            this.firstElement = objects[0];
            objects[0] = defaultText;
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            label.setText(objects[position]);

            return row;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong here but it could help us to see your `CustomSpinnerAdapter` as well.